# Parallel in Workflow

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand how parallel workflows work, so I started developing a simple script for the job. But cannot understand how to retrieve (or even save) the information.
**EDIT** : Forgot to mention that the following code doesn't work as I expected.

```
$wks ='wks1.domain.com','wks2.domain.com','wks3.domain.com'

workflow ExampleWorkflow{
    param ($wks_list)

    $array_workflow = @()

    foreach -Parallel ($workstation in $wks_list){
        $processes = Get-Process -PSComputerName $workstation
        foreach($process in $processes){
            $info = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $process.ID
            $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ProcessName -Value $process.ProcessName
            $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name RAM -Value $process.PM
            $info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name WKS -Value $workstation

            $WORKFLOW:array_workflow += $info
        }
    }
}
ExampleWorkflow $wks
```

Can someone help me understand how to manipulate data inside the workflow so that after that can be accessible after exiting the workflow?

Comment: You can't use objects in workflows.  Try playing around with an `inlinescript {}` block inside your foreach.  You can load the output of your inlinescript block into a variable, but it still cannot be an object.  In these instances I typically export as JSON and then reconvert to an object outside the workflow.

Comment: Could you give me an example how you do that? For example I do `$array_workflow | ConvertTo-Json` inside the workflow. But where is it stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with the code, with some help from the answers and some research, came up with this solution that worked for me:

```
$wks ='wks1.domain.com','wks2.domain.com','wks3.domain.com'

workflow ExampleWorkflow{
    param ($wks_list)

    foreach -Parallel ($workstation in $wks_list){
        InlineScript{
            $processes = Get-Process -ComputerName $using:workstation
            foreach($process in $processes){
                $obj = New-Object -type PSObject -Property  @{ 
                    ID = $process.ID
                    ProcessName = $process.ProcessName
                    Memory = ($process.PM / 1MB)
                    Workstation = $using:desktop
                }
                Write-Output $obj
            }
        }
    }
}
$var = ExampleWorkflow $wks
Do-Stuff with $var
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correct, I believe Workflows create PS jobs which are launched in the back ground. Cmdlets like get-job and receive-job would be used to get this data. Check out receive-job -keep, this will keep the job data. If you use it without the data disappears after it's executed.